# swift 2 iOS 9 - Task running after app destruction: how do it?

Tags: ios, swift2

I'm newbie in iOS App world so pardon me if my questions are simple and banals

I have this scenario:

- my server side generates MQTT messages on a well known topic
- my app can connect to the MQTT Topic and can receive messages

All works pretty good; what I would like to do now is the following (if possible)

When the user stops the app (by deleting it from the task manager) I'd like to have a kind of service able in being connected (or remaining connected) to the MQTT Topic; in this way also when the app is no more running I can receive MQTT messages

Basically I'd love to have something similar to Facebook messenger that is able in receiving messages also when the app is not running

NOTE: i can't use remote notification mechanism provide by Apple

Answer (score 0):

Remote notifications would be perfect for this, shame that it's not an option for you. 
There are a few other situations where apps can run periodically on the background, they are described here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

BUT, from that page: "In most cases, the system does not relaunch apps after they are force quit by the user."
So in general an app will run in background only if the user exits it normally, not if he forces it to quit in the task manager.

Comment: thank you for the answer; I already saw the link you mentioned and I wrote the needed code for the "background fetch" as described in the Apple documentation; I was wondering if I could use some other approach... If remote notifications fit with my requirement...I'll try to push my boss in using them.... also because without remote notification I always have the limit of 64 local notification and I should use some kind of cache in order to store all MQTT messages that exceed the 64 notifications... Thank you for the feedback :)